# dc.js Can a Pie Legend be recentered after filtering

Tags: dc.js

I would like to be able to recenter a Pie charts legend after it has been filtered.  Slices/Legends will removed when filtering because we remove empty bins.  I added a pretransition listener to chart2, but that seems to be to late because the legend y value is the previous value and not current.

```
.on('pretransition', chart => buildLegend (chart))
```

If Male is selected on the Gender Pie chart I want the 4 legend items on the Job Pie chart to be re-centered.  Any suggestions?

You can see a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/woolycew65/fvh4wgcu/) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more digging around showed me how to reference and update SVG elements.

```
function recenterLegend(chart) {
    chart.selectAll('g.dc-legend')
        .attr('transform', function(d) {
            let legendY = (300 - (chart.group().all().length * 16)) / 2;
            let translate = 'translate(220,' + legendY + ')';
            return translate ;
         });
    }
```

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/woolycew65/fvh4wgcu/1/).